# How to convert Autocad lines to Esri polygon shapefiles using FME?

Tags: fme-form

I am using FME to transform a dwg file into a polygon shapefile (.shp).

The dwg file is an urban plan of a city consisting of building blocks (type: polylines) and the properties within each block (type : line).

I used the **GeometryCoercer** transformer to convert type:line to type:polygon but it does not seem to work. I have also tried **AreaBuilder**, no success.

For those familiar with the FME software can you suggest Any solutions?

**UPDATE**

I attach an image of the dwg file (INPUT)
[image]

green closed polylines represent building blocks
orange lines represent properties

I used the workspace as provided by @Mapperz, but it didnt work out.
I set the **geometry coercer**  *type : fme_line* , then **2dForcer** and **AREA BUILDER** writing to a .shp with attributed geometry *shape_polygon*. This is what I get.

[image]

When I set the output .shp geometry to *shape_polyline* I get the following [image]

I need a shapefile where all buildings and all properties will have a polygon geometry in order to add attributes to each polygon.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a small sample area of your data?

Comment: From the screenshots I think you need to make your purple polygons into lines then use the feature merger to have all your lines together - then build polygons - they are currently separate layers. http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/FMETransformers.htm#transformers/featuremerger.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using FME 2013 beta here**

read the CAD [DXF]
control the geometry - GeometryCoercer (FMEline)
control the geometry - Force 2D (2d line only)

Build the Polygons

Output port AREA

Write Shapefile

See Image - as proof of concept.

[image]

Comment: response given as an update to the original question.

Comment: Source Data: http://data.vancouver.ca/datacatalogue/index.htm Cadastral boundaries DWG

Answer (score 1):

with autocad map this can be accomplished fairly easily.
Perhaps the first thing you should do is to close the polylines that  may give you a better polygon result.